# C# how to find image inside larger image in around 500-700 milliseconds?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, bitmap, scanning

I've been working on image recognition that grabs the screen using bitmap in winforms at 727, 115 area every 700 milliseconds. The get set pixel method is a way to slow and any other method I have found I don't really know how to use.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        g.CopyFromScreen(896, 1250, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

Bitmap myPic = Resources.SARCUT;
```

This creates the image on the area on the screen, and the myPic image is the image needing to be found in a 727, 115 area, as stated before. I've tried using aForge, Emgu, and LockPixel but I couldn't convert the bitmaps to the right format and never got it to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Contour Analysis for Image Recognition in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196168/Contour-Analysis-for-Image-Recognition-in-C) -- [Image Recognition with Neural Networks](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19323/Image-Recognition-with-Neural-Networks)

Comment: There is a New Bitmap(width, height, Pixelformat)  constructur, if you want to change the format. If you want only a part of the Screen, you should make your bitmap smaller. You try to copy something from the screen, beyond right and bottom border, probably.
The last line of code has nothing to do with your Request ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitmap and any image operation, together with rendering, is handled by GDI+ in .NET. The GDI+ albeit being faster than its predecessor GDI, it's still notably slow. Also, you seem to be performing a copy operation and this will always represent a performance hit. If you really need to improve performance you should not use the GDI+ framework, this means you have  to operate on bitmaps directly and at a lower level. However, this last statement is very broad because it depends on exactly what you want to accomplish and how. Finally, if you want to compare two images you should avoid doing it pixel by pixel and instead do it byte by byte, it's faster since no indexing format and no value encoding has to be taken into account.